# If value = null then " " else value SSRS EXPRESSION issues

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

value 1 is a retail price decimal value 2 is the difference between 2 retail costs both are decimals

```
=IIF(Fields!Prorated.Value is null,"",Fields!Prorated.Value)-Fields!Retail.Value fixxed !!!
```

Fixxed ^^

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Prorated.Value),"",(Fields!Prorated.Value-Fields!CurrentRetailPrice.Value)/Fields!Prorated.Value)
```

Failed ^^ this one is shown as a % difference

this has not worked what would be another way around this

Comment: You'll find you get better answers if instead of "this has not worked" you describe what you expect to happen, what happened instead, and any error messages you're seeing. Also, what value do you actually want if Prorated is null? (Hint: "" is not a number)

Comment: @MattGibson what i expect to happen is to show blank if prorated = null 

(Hint: i am a BI report dev, i dont decide on what is wanted i just give them what they want)

Comment: by blank i mean "" exactly how the question was asked

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!days_Prorated.Value),"",Fields!Prorated.Value-Fields!Retail.Value)
```

For your comment try this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Prorated.Value),"",(Fields!Prorated.Value-Fields!CurrentRetailPrice.Value)/iif(Isnothing(Fields!Prorated.Value),1,Fields!Prorated.Value)
```

You have to validate it twice in this case.

Comment: it worked for my first column but for my second it didnt 

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Prorated.Value),"",(Fields!Prorated.Value-Fields!CurrentRetailPrice.Value)/Fields!Prorated.Value)