# SRSS Switch with filter keeps throwing error

Tags: sql, vba, reporting-services

I've been trying to adjust this multiple times thinking that my null checks are broken. Referenced a null check form here: [IIF Statement Null Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716829/if-value-null-then-else-value-ssrs-expression-issues)

That did nto seem to work for my case. Anyway, if anyone could take a quick look and see if they can see the mistake that would be great.

```
 =SWITCH(
Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Additional Repair Proposal Submitted - Pending Award", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 60), Today)),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Repair Award*", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmADelvTerms.Value + Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 90), Today)),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Award Received - Pending Shipment For Assessment" & Fields!vendor.Value, "H" or "I", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmADelvTerms.Value + Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 90), Fields!lmiiiSAAwardDate.Value)),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Award Received - Pending Shipment For Assessment" & Fields!vendor.Value, "A" or "B" or "C" or "D" or "E" or "F" or "G", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmADelvTerms.Value + Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 30), Fields!lmiiiSAAwardDate.Value)),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Undergoing Assessment at Repair Facility", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmArmaDelvTerms.Value + fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 30), Fields!lmVendorStartDateAssess.Value)),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Assessment Complete - Pending Action", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 60), Fields!lmAssessCompleteDate.Value)),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Final Repair Awarded" and Not(IsNothing(Fields!EstDelivDate.Value)), Year(Fields!EstDelivDate.Value),

Fields!lmItemStatus.Value, "Final Repair Awarded" and IsNothing(Fields!EstDelivDate.Value), Year(Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 30), Today)
```

The error I keep getting is a conversion error From "Lom" to type "Long" is nto valid.

Comment: Take out each case until you find the culprit, then correct it

Comment: I'll try that now. I'm wondering if it's the way I"m trying to check for Null Values in the last two statements.

Comment: So basically none of them are working. If I go all the way down to the first one alone it throws a conversion string Dispsoed DRMO to Type Boolean is not valid. So maybe I have to find another way to parse the year out if a string exists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out- there were multiple errors inside my code. In line

```
Fields!lmItemStatus.Value = "Award Received - Pending Shipment For Assessment" & Fields!vendor.Value, "A" or "B" or "C" or "D" or "E" or "F" or "G", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmADelvTerms.Value + Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 30), Fields!lmiiiSAAwardDate.Value)),
```

I did not realize I could not actually use a "or" or "and" inside of a switch. I had to split this into a separate switch for each string ie:

```
Fields!lmItemStatus.Value = "Award Received - Pending Shipment For Assessment" & Fields!vendor.Value = "A", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmADelvTerms.Value + Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 30), Fields!lmiiiSAAwardDate.Value)),
Fields!lmItemStatus.Value = "Award Received - Pending Shipment For Assessment" & Fields!vendor.Value = "B", Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmADelvTerms.Value + Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 30), Fields!lmiiiSAAwardDate.Value)),
```

Also I was trying to parse the dates out. I did not need to do that.

Comment: Wrong use of switch, see StevenWhite suggestion. Also OR, AND expressions are allowed in the switch on the condition part, see examples at  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8691c7fd-1526-426d-95fc-f9ecfc3d26cf/ssrs-case-statement?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Yeah, that's why I put my own answer. Because I figured it out and made a repost. Why did I get a negative for posting the correct answer? Stevens answer only partially answered my question so I did not rep him.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is wrong and may confuse others. As I mentioned OR, AND are allowed eg in your answer it could be Switch( Fields!lmItemStatus.Value = "Award Received - Pending Shipment For Assessment" AND (Fields!vendor.Value = "A" OR Fields!vendor.Value = "B"), ....    Use parentheses to control the condition evaluation order.

Comment: Understood. Use of the parentheses is for brevity and less lines.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. The `Switch` function takes pairs of arguments. These need to be an expression that evaluates to true or false and the second is the result if it's true. So it should look like this:

```
=Switch(Fields!lmItemStatus.Value = "Additional Repair Proposal Submitted - Pending Award"
    , Year(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, (Fields!lmFinalDelvTerms.Value + 60), Today))
    , ...)
```

Comment: Uhhh... I fail to see the difference in your example and mine? It looks like you moved the comma down onto the next row and nothing else.

Comment: Notice the = sign after the item status instead of a comma. You need to have pairs of 2 arguments, not 3.

Comment: Gotcha - funny enough I noticed that was one of my issues without realizing the = sign in your post. However, that did not fully answer the problem. That was a partial issue I missed thinking it was structured the same as an IIF statement. The other issue I had was the "and" / "or" inside of my switch.